# Unable to distribute messages correctly from Kafka Soures to Hazelcast Jet Clusters

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, distributed, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

We are using Kafka as a source for our Jet job. 
We expect to distribute the messages received in Kafka to each Jet instance running on different machines.

We are able to join the members from different machines successfully using GroupConfig (setting name and password) and JoinConfig (to add ip addresses).

When we send a message into a Kafka source topic, either all the machines read the same message or the same message is processed twice on one single machine.

For example, we have a Kafka topic created with **4** partitions and
**2** different machines running with exactly **1** jet cluster.
When we run the application and instantiate the jet instance, we see that the **2** jet members are joined and the partitions are split between the **2**.

When a message like "message_one" is sent, then either of these two happens:

1. Message is read by both Jet instances
2. Message is read twice by only one of the Jet instances

Neither are desired in our case, as we don't want the messages to be duplicated.

How to prevent processing the message twice?

Below is the code snippet:

```java
    JetConfig jetConfig = new JetConfig();
    jetConfig.getInstanceConfig().setCooperativeThreadCount(1);
    jetConfig.getInstanceConfig().setFlowControlPeriodMs(200);
    jetConfig.getHazelcastConfig().getGroupConfig().setName("TEST_NAME");
    jetConfig.getHazelcastConfig().getGroupConfig().setPassword("TEST_PASSWORD");
    jetConfig.getHazelcastConfig().getNetworkConfig().setReuseAddress(true);

    final JoinConfig join = jetConfig.getHazelcastConfig().getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
    join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    join.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).addMember("test.ip.address.one");
    join.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).addMember("test.ip.address.two");
    jetConfig.getHazelcastConfig().getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces()
            .setEnabled(true)
            .addInterface("test.ip.address.one")
            .addInterface("test.ip.address.two");

    final JetInstance jet =Jet.newJetInstance(jetConfig);


    final Properties consumeProps = new Properties();
    final Properties produceProps=new Properties();
    consumeProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers);           
    consumeProps.setProperty("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getCanonicalName());          
    consumeProps.setProperty("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getCanonicalName());
    consumeProps.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    consumeProps.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    consumeProps.setProperty("group.id", kafkaLoadBalancerGroupName);
    consumeProps.setProperty("partition.assignment.strategy", RoundRobinAssignor.class.getCanonicalName());

    produceProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers);   
    produceProps.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
    produceProps.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());

    final Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
    p.drawFrom(KafkaSources.kafka(consumeProps, kafkaSourceTopic))
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .map(TestClass::parseMessage)
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .drainTo(KafkaSinks.kafka(produceProps, kafkaEnrichedTopic));
    jet.newJob(p).join();
```

Comment: This should not happen. The shared code looks o.k. You might want to have a look at the `KafkaSource` sample here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/0.5-maintenance/streaming/kafka-source/src/main/java/KafkaSource.java

Comment: Jet uses manual partition assignment for Kafka, so you should remove `group.id` and `partition.assignment.strategy` properties, maybe they're interfering with how the partitions are assigned. You should also remove `enable.auto.commit` as this will also interfere with snapshotting.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the reply.
@CanGencer We removed the properties mentioned in your comment. Still we are facing the same issue. Do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: @ek_cool could you edit your code to show the latest state?